# Logging python dictionary where values may have unicode errors

Tags: python, dictionary, logging, format, python-unicode

I am trying to add verbose logs, to an existing script. This script fetches data through a soap client API, into a dictionary. I am using logging module and format function to log this dictionary as is.

In some, cases I am getting unicode exception as below, because a value may have non-ascii characters, resulting in exceptions.

**Sample Ref:**

```
ref = {'Name': 'John', 'Surname': 'Doe', 'MI': None, 'Title':  u'\xe2\x80\xa2\tEngineer_I'}
```

> *'\xe2\x80\xa2\tEngineer_I', is .encode('utf-8') representation of the value returned though below query.*

**Present code:**

```
logger = logging.getLogger(name)
ref_data = soap_query()
for ref in ref_data:
    logger.debug("This is the reference data: {}".format(ref))
```

**Error:**

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2022' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack.py", line 65, in <module>
    query_db(db_obj)
  File "stack.py", line 50, in query_db
    logger.info("This is the reference data: {}".format(ref))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2022' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

**Workaround**

To get around this, I wrote another function as below:

```
# Dictionary comprehension to encode all unicode values as ascii and ignore errors
def convert_to_str(ref):
    return {k: v.encode('ascii', 'ignore') if v else v for k, v in ref.iteritems()}
```

**Any better solution?**

This works for me but i want to know, if there is any better approach to handle this?
Can i pass any argument to logger or format function to encode as ascii or ignore unicode errors?

I am using **Python 2.7.6**

Comment: could you make a standalone reproducible example? And it would be even better if you share it in an online sandbox. I'm trying to reproduce it, but with no success, everything seems fine. Maybe a console or another logging target you use can't process unicode characters?

Comment: my bad, i share the ref dict after running it through convert_to_str function. "\xe2\x80\xa2\t" these are special characters in the string when I print them with .encode('utf-8'). Updated utf-8 representation in the question as well

Comment: not sure how to provide online sandbox, is there any doc, link i can follow to provide this?

Comment: What's the full stack trace of the error?

Comment: @akshat for example, you can make it here: https://repl.it

Comment: @twasbrillig, added traceback in question

Comment: @OlegRybalchenko, i am unable to reproduce the issue there, in interactive shells and  https://repl.it. But can easily reproduce it, when i run the script

Answer (score 0):

you can use str() convert dict to string,following this code

```
logger = logging.getLogger(name)
ref_data = soap_query()
for ref in ref_data:
    logger.debug("This is the reference data: {}".format(str(ref)))
```

Comment: thanks for taking time to answer. However, i am afraif, this is default behaviour of format function and does not cover my usecase